# add a third party controllers to aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I want to add a third party controllers to my aspx.

I download it and install it. then i compied the dll files to my bin and i added theses dll to my reference. I can see the controllers in my aspx page but i am not able to use them im my c# code .

#### i am sure i have done something wrong in my web.config

This is all my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      <pages>
        <controls>
             <add tagPrefix="ew"  namespace="eWorld.UI.Compatibility" assembly="eWorld.UI.Compatibility"/>
        </controls>
      </pages>

    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

#### this is my aspx page

```
<ew:calendarpopup ID="CldrSchCallBack" runat="server" Text="Date" Nullable="true" Width="75px" ButtonStyle-ForeColor="#640064"
    ButtonStyle-BorderColor="#640064" ButtonStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" ButtonStyle-BorderWidth="1"/>&nbsp;  
    <ew:timepicker ID="TimePicker1" runat="server" Text="Time" Nullable="true" Width="75px" ButtonStyle-ForeColor="#640064" 
    ButtonStyle-BorderColor="#640064" ButtonStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" ButtonStyle-BorderWidth="1"/>
```

#### my problem

I can't use this in my code

```
CldrSchCallBack.SelectedValue.HasValue 
TimePicker1.SelectedValue.HasValue
```

because I got this error:

```
Error   1   The name 'CldrSchCallBack' does not exist in the current context    C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TestC1\TestC1\CallInfo.aspx.cs  537 120 TestC1
Error   2   The name 'TimePicker1' does not exist in the current context    C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TestC1\TestC1\CallInfo.aspx.cs  537 162 TestC1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this control on my machine, first I've downloaded version 2.0.6 then referenced the two dlls: eWorld.UI.Compatibility.dll and eWorld.UI.dll.

Then I modified web.config file like this:

```
  <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="eWorld.UI.Compatibility, Version=2.0.6.2393, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24D65337282035F2"/>
        <add assembly="eWorld.UI, Version=2.0.6.2393, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24D65337282035F2"/>
      </assemblies>    
    </compilation>        
    <pages>
            <controls>
              <add tagPrefix="ew"  namespace="eWorld.UI.Compatibility" assembly="eWorld.UI.Compatibility"/>
            </controls>
          </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Another way might be adding this at the top of the aspx page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="eWorld.UI, Version=2.0.6.2393, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24d65337282035f2"
Namespace="eWorld.UI" TagPrefix="ew" %>
```

Of course you should change the version number to the version you're using. Try that and it's better to post more of your aspx page markup, that would help finding solutions faster.